# Calling a callback passed from another class

Tags: c++, callback, c++17, pointer-to-member

I want to register a callback handler (method) of the one class (Y) in another (X). I can't use std::function because of possible heap allocation and I must have an access to members of a class that registers the handler. I also want to avoid static functions.
I've came up with some workaournd but got stuck on calling the callback:

```
template<class T>
using clbkType = void(T::*)(void);

template<class T>
class X
{
public:

    void registerClbck(clbkType<T> clbk) {
        callback = clbk;
    }

    void call() {
        callback(); // ERROR C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments.
        //(((X<T>*)this)->X<T>::callback)(); // same error

    }
private:
    clbkType<T> callback;
};

class Y
{
public:

    Y() {
        x.registerClbck(&Y::handler);
    }

    // just for a test: fire a callback in class X
    void fire() {
        x.call();
    }

    int getA() { return a; }
private:
    int a{ 0 };
    X<Y> x{};

    void handler() {
        a = 5;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Y y;
    y.fire();
    return y.getA();
}
```

link to code: https://godbolt.org/z/PhY41xsWE

PS. I'm not sure if this is a safe solution, so please put any comment on that.

Thanks!

Comment: Your description does not mention lifetime concerns.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont: class X shall live as long as class Y. I guess there would be a failure if Y no longer lives and X calls a callback to it, however here, X object is a member of Y so it's okay I suppose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The member function pointer needs a specific class object to invoke, so you need to do this:

```
template<class T>
class X
{
public:
    // ...
    void call(T& obj) {
      (obj.*callback)();
    }
    // ...
};

class Y
{
public:
    // just for a test: fire a callback in class X
    void fire() {
      x.call(*this);
    }
    // ...  
};
```

[Demo.](https://godbolt.org/z/4b1cWz63a)

Answer (score 1):

The member function pointer need an instance to be called on.

If you want to bind the instance, here is a possible way to implement it.

```
template<typename T>
struct member_callback {
    T* instance;
    void(T::*callback)();
    void operator()(){(instance->*callback)();}
};

template<typename T>
struct X{
    void registerClbck(member_callback<T> clbk) { callback = clbk; }
    void call() { callback(); }
    member_callback<T> callback;
};

struct Y{
public:
    Y() { x.registerClbck({this,&Y::handler}); }
    void fire() { x.call(); }
    int getA() { return a; }
private:
    int a{ 0 };
    X<Y> x{};
    void handler(){ a = 5; }
};

int main()
{
    Y y;
    y.fire();
    return y.getA();
}
```